# Graph API only returns page posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, field, facebook-page

Im using the Graph API to get certain data from my managed pages.
What i need is the likes, checkins and talking_about_count from my pages.
When i add checkins and talking_about_count i get an error that the API doesn't know the fields.
So i removed those and only asked for the likes and id.
What the API returns is a list with the posts from the page and only showing the id, creation date and the likes(if there are any).

I tested with some other fields like about and website, but they give the same error as checkins and talking_about_count, so i can't get basic data from my pages..

The link i use is this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/168707433219493/feed?access_token=[Access_Token]&fields=id,likes,checkins,talking_about_count
```

And the error i get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: checkins,talking_about_count.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

When i only ask for id and likes i get:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "168707433219493_333476503426186",
         "created_time": "2012-11-28T19:38:57+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "168707433219493_370257573064477",
         "created_time": "2012-11-22T08:12:11+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "168707433219493_423778884356339",
         "likes": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "Guido van Tricht",
                  "id": "1117357415"
               }
            ],
            "count": 1
         },
         "created_time": "2012-11-19T22:46:01+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/168707433219493/feed?fields=id,likes&access_token=[Access_Token]&limit=25&since=1354131537&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/168707433219493/feed?fields=id,likes&access_token=[Access_Token]&limit=25&until=1350819853"
   }
}
```

I hope someone knows how to solve my problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`talking_about_count` should be in the `/PAGE_ID`, not in the feed.

Why not get this data from:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/168707433219493?access_token=[Access_Token]
```

Comment: So the other link is only for the wall feed and only returns posts?

Comment: Are you having trouble reading docs …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections